# Could someone explain the regex /(.*)\.(.*)/?

Tags: regex

I want to get the file extension in Groovy with a regex, for let's say `South.6987556.Input.csv.cop`.

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html shows me that the second group would really contain the `cop` extension. Which is what I want.

```
0: [0,27] South.6987556.Input.csv.cop
1: [0,23] South.6987556.Input.csv
2: [24,27] cop
```

I just don't understand why the result won't be

```
0: [0,27] South.6987556.Input.csv.cop
1: [0,23] South
2: [24,27] 6987556.Input.csv.cop
```

What should be the regex to get this kind of result?

Comment: The reason is that the (.*) is "greedy" - it will gobble up as many characters as possible. To make it not-greedy, add a question mark. `(.*?)\.(.*)`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's in the title.

Comment: Does the last `?` belongs to the regex or not? Why don't you  play with [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/1)?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean ... [You also probably want `(.*?)\.(.*)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989252/could-someone-explain-reg-exp/24989310#comment38850267_24989252)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: no, ? is not part of the reg exp. I updated the title

Comment: @Alec: could you make an answer from your comment so I can except it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a visualization of this regex

```
(.*)\.(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SxIIx4AAj67Da3Y-)

in words

- `(.*)` matches anything als large as possible and references it
- `\.` matches **one** period, no reference (no brackets)
- `(.*)` matches anything again, may be empty, and references it

in your case this is

- `(.*)` : `South.6987556.Input.csv`
- `\.` : `.`
- `(.*)` : `cop`

it isn't just only `South` and `6987556.Input.csv.cop` because the first part `(.*)` isn't optional but greedy and must be followed by a period, so the engine tries to match the largest possible string.

Your intended result would be created by this regex: `(.*?)\.(.*)`. The `?` after a quantifier (in this case `*`) switches the behaviour of the engine to ungreedy, so the smallest matching string will be searched. By default most regex engines are greedy.

Comment: no, it still allows, like before, to have a filename with en empty extension

Comment: argh... right... I forgot the `*` and thought about `+`... sry... you're right

Comment: @bukart it won't capture the entire string.

Comment: updated my answere corresponding to the updated regex in the title

Comment: I was mainly about the explanation of the desired and working well reg exp `(.*)\.(.*)`. Thank you.

Comment: @bukart : **question :** why doesn't `\.` matches `.` after `South` but only before `cop`?

Comment: @NoobEditor: because the first group (.*) catches as many characters as possible to the last dot. That's what I understood. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To get the desired output, your regex should be:

```
((.*?)\.(.*))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/2)

See the captured groups at right bottom of the DEMO site.

**Explanation:**

```
(         group and capture to \1:
  (       group and capture to \2:
    .*?   any character except \n (0 or more
          times) ? after *  makes the regex engine
          to does a non-greedy match(shortest possible match).
  )       end of \2
  \.      '.'
  (       group and capture to \3:
    .*    any character except \n (0 or more
          times)
  )       end of \3
)         end of \1
```